# Need help doing or need help in doing?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

- Do you need help in doing something?
- Do you need help doing something?

Which one is correct?
I've heard sentences like the second one many times. But I don't think it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are correct when **Help** is used as a noun.